# How do you make a custom shape for a sprite from a multiple sprite sheet in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I took a sprite sheet from the Internet and began slicing it in the Unity sprite editor. It was going well, when I found a sprite that was too close to another sprite to encapsulate the whole sprite without cutting off the top of the one below it! My only non-invasive option was to modify the outline of the shape that you use to cut off individual sprites from a sprite sheet. So how do you make a polygon-shaped sprite slice? [picture of my sprite sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkDql.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to change the geometry of a sprite in Unity from a rectangular shape. I am not a rendering expert, but the increase in geometry would add unnecessary overhead to the sprite drawing process.

Your best bet is to edit the sprite sheet in an image editing program such as Photoshop or GIMP, so that all sprites fit into a grid form, or at least a form where they don't violate each other's rectangular bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable polygon mode. Polygon mode will save space but isn't friendly to rectangle mode.